500 Error on website using VPS and DIRECTUS
So i have a website for a bar, hosted using a VPS, with a MYSQL database. I'm also using DIRECTUS as a CMS. As you can see on the wesite, it works, for the most part. On one page, all the images show with no problems. But on another page, with the same layout, only some of the images will show, the others not. They all have 500 errors in the dev tools (there is also a code error in the console, but has nothing to do with the problem as far as I can tell):

All the images have the exact same permissions on the server, which are the following :

I see no reason for some images to be visible, others not, seeing as though they were uploaded through Directus, are hosted on the same server, in the same folder, with the same permissions. If anyone has any ideas on what to do, or where the problem is coming from, i'd be very grateful, I'm lost right now.
EDIT :
So after searching for a little while in every error log i could find, the only ones i can fin are these (from the nginx logs) :
From the access log :

From the error log :
2024/04/08 12:16:32 [crit] 175647#175647: *18226 SSL_do_handshake() failed (SSL: error:0A00006C:SSL routines::bad key share) while SSL handshaking, client: redacted, server: 0.0.0.0:443
Not sure if any of this will help.

Please share  more details, like the error message involved. Usually, the server's error log contains more detail if an error 500 occurs

This seems to be a bug in an application. You must contact their customer support / forum for help as without actual code and understanding its context, there is little we can do.

Your key parameter (?key=thumb) appears to be breaking the request. That value must not be authenticated to make that request.
The following URL (provided by you) would work just fine:
https://api.hopstorelyon.fr/assets/2296f6ef-8e26-4024-b207-3972a9c5acaf

This worked great, don't know how i missed that. Thanks !
